# Cannot get $q.all with nested promises working - wait for all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I fully understand that similar questions have been asked before but I don't get it running. I need a chain of promises and I need to wait until all promises are resolved.

My issue is that I need to call different promises based on the outcome of another promise :-(

So based on the outcome of **promise2** my **promise4** is **EITHER** *$translate.use* **OR** it is *$translate.refresh*.

This is what I have so far (simplified):

```js
      
      var promise1 = someService.get({}).$promise.then(function (result) {
         // do stuff
      });

      var promise2 = anotherService.getPromise().then(function (result) {
        var properties = result[0];
        // do stuff
        return properties;
      });

      var promise3 = promise2.then(function(properties){

        // using $translate (angular-translate) here which is async as well

        var userLanguage = properties.language;
        if (userLanguage !== $translate.preferredLanguage()) {
          // either this is the 4th promise
          $translate.use(userLanguage).then(function (myVar) {
            // ...
          });
        } else {
          // or this is the 4th promise
          $translate.refresh().then(function (myVar) {
            // ...
          });
        }
      });

      var loadPromises = {
        promise1: promise1
        promise2: promise2
        promise3: promise3
        promise4: ???
      };

      $q.all(loadPromises).then(function (result) {
        // anything done
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to monitor `promise3` and `promise4`, all you need is `promise1` and `promise2`. `promise3` becomes next step of the `promise2`. Just note how you return new promise (either `return $translate.use` or `return $translate.refresh`) from `promise2` then part :

```
var promise1 = someService.get({}).$promise.then(function(result) {
  // do stuff
});

var promise2 = anotherService.getPromise().then(function(result) {
  var properties = result[0];
  // do stuff
  return properties;
})
.then(function(properties) {

  // using $translate (angular-translate) here which is async as well

  var userLanguage = properties.language;
  if (userLanguage !== $translate.preferredLanguage()) {
    // either this is the 4th promise
    return $translate.use(userLanguage).then(function(myVar) {
      // ...
    });
  } else {
    // or this is the 4th promise
    return $translate.refresh().then(function(myVar) {
      // ...
    });
  }
});

var loadPromises = {
  promise1: promise1,
  promise2: promise2
};

$q.all(loadPromises).then(function(result) {
  // anything done
});
```

Comment: That's not quite the same as the logic in OP. It's true that `promise3` was broken and the `return`  statements were missing, but `promise2` was fine and can be kept as is. This would give access to the result of that promise to the "all" promise, as in OP.

Comment: @Amit It's true that this my code won't have promise2 result available in $q.all block, however my understanding is that OP doesn't really need it, otherwise they would probably (?) not chain promise3 to it. But of course you are correct, and if it's needed, then it's still easy to adjust.

Comment: If that's the need, why have that last `then` handler at all? The code simply continue from the former function to the latter, without the return statement and extra promise chain.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code well enough, I think you only need to return the inner promise inside of `promise3`.  In your example, both `promise1` and `promise2` won't be resolved until the service is done.  Since `promise3` depends on `promise2` it won't finish until `promise2` resolved.  I believe `$q.all` keeps going until all promises are complete, even promises returned by promises.  Since `promise3` returns a promise, `promise3` won't be considered resolved until the inner promise is resolved. So, I think adding a couple `return` statements is all that you need:

```
  var promise1 = someService.get({}).$promise.then(function (result) {
     // do stuff
  });

  var promise2 = anotherService.getPromise().then(function (result) {
    var properties = result[0];
    // do stuff
    return properties;
  });

  var promise3 = promise2.then(function(properties){

    // using $translate (angular-translate) here which is async as well

    var userLanguage = properties.language;
    if (userLanguage !== $translate.preferredLanguage()) {
      // either this is the 4th promise
      //NOTE: added return here
      return $translate.use(userLanguage).then(function (myVar) {
        // ...
      });
    } else {
      // or this is the 4th promise
      //NOTE: added return here
      return $translate.refresh().then(function (myVar) {
        // ...
      });
    }
  });

  var loadPromises = {
    promise1: promise1,
    promise2: promise2,
    promise3: promise3
  };

  $q.all(loadPromises).then(function (result) {
    // anything done
  });
```